# Duplicate Records On Join

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, airflow

New to `BigQuery`.

In `inventory` table, the granurality is `depot_id` and `product_id`, and `inventorytransaction` table has each operation (either addition or subtraction) logs done from `inventory` table.

What is needed is to get sum of quantity for each month(Jan to Dec) of the current year as extra columns in `inventory` table `SELECT` like so

```
SELECT inventory.*, janTotalQuantity, febTotalQuantity, marTotalQuantity,...
```

What i tried is `LEFT JOIN` inventory table with a subquery that gets total quantity per depot and product for month-year(e.g Jan-2019, Feb-2019, Mar-2019,...). Below is the `SQL` statement that does just that.

```
SELECT inv.inventory_id, p.product_name, p.product_type, p.product_distributor as distributor, p.product_category as category, d.depot_name as location, inv.quantity, inv.lower_limit, inv.unit_cost, inv.quantity * inv.unit_cost as value, p.product_id, d.depot_id, TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(inv.update_date) as last_update, inv.delete_status, IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Jan-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0) AS janQuantityTotal,IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Feb-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0) AS febQuantityTotal,IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Mar-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0) AS marQuantityTotal,IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Apr-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0) AS aprQuantityTotal,IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "May-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0) AS mayQuantityTotal,IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Jun-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0) AS junQuantityTotal,IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Jul-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0) AS julQuantityTotal,IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Aug-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0) AS augQuantityTotal,IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Sep-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0) AS sepQuantityTotal,IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Oct-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0) AS octQuantityTotal,IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Nov-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0) AS novQuantityTotal,IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Dec-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0) AS decQuantityTotal      
FROM iprocure_stage.inventory inv
JOIN iprocure_ods.product p ON p.product_id = inv.product_id 
JOIN iprocure_ods.depot d ON d.depot_id = inv.depot_id
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%b-%Y', transaction_date) mon_year, product_id, depot_id, SUM(quantity) as totalQuantity
     FROM `iprocure_ods.inventorytransaction`
     WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = {{ execution_date.year }}
                AND transaction_type = 1 AND (reference_type = 1 OR reference_type = 6) AND delete_status = 0
                GROUP BY mon_year, product_id, depot_id 
 ) AS agg_sd ON agg_sd.product_id = inv.product_id AND agg_sd.depot_id = inv.depot_id
```

The problem with the above query is that for every month's total quantity of a given depot-product, duplicates inventory record, like so

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  inventory_id    depot_id    product_id    janTotalQuantity    febTotalQuantity
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    123             2             3              56                   0
    123             2             3              0                    65
```

How can i avoid duplication of `inventory` table and add monthly total quantity columns in BigQuery

Comment: Simplify your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex. Show us some sample table data and the expected result (as formatted text, no images.)

Comment: @jarlh, i have added sample table data

Comment: update your question and add  the expcted  result  (you rows are not duplicated ) so could be you mean something other for duplicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by evertyhing outside your partial sums and apply SUM aggregation function on those. This should flatten your output dataset:

```
SELECT inv.inventory_id, p.product_name, p.product_type, p.product_distributor as distributor, p.product_category as category, d.depot_name as location, inv.quantity, inv.lower_limit, inv.unit_cost, inv.quantity * inv.unit_cost as value, p.product_id, d.depot_id, TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(inv.update_date) as last_update, inv.delete_status,
SUM(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Jan-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS janQuantityTotal,
SUM(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Feb-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS febQuantityTotal,
SUM(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Mar-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS marQuantityTotal,
SUM(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Apr-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS aprQuantityTotal,
SUM(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "May-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS mayQuantityTotal,
SUM(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Jun-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS junQuantityTotal,
SUM(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Jul-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS julQuantityTotal,
SUM(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Aug-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS augQuantityTotal,
SUM(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Sep-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS sepQuantityTotal,
SUM(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Oct-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS octQuantityTotal,
SUM(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Nov-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS novQuantityTotal,
SUM(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Dec-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS decQuantityTotal      
FROM iprocure_stage.inventory inv
JOIN iprocure_ods.product p ON p.product_id = inv.product_id 
JOIN iprocure_ods.depot d ON d.depot_id = inv.depot_id
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%b-%Y', transaction_date) mon_year, product_id, depot_id, SUM(quantity) as totalQuantity
     FROM `iprocure_ods.inventorytransaction`
     WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = {{ execution_date.year }}
                AND transaction_type = 1 AND (reference_type = 1 OR reference_type = 6) AND delete_status = 0
                GROUP BY mon_year, product_id, depot_id 
 ) AS agg_sd ON agg_sd.product_id = inv.product_id AND agg_sd.depot_id = inv.depot_id
GROUP BY inv.inventory_id, p.product_name, p.product_type, p.product_distributor as distributor, p.product_category as category, d.depot_name as location, inv.quantity, inv.lower_limit, inv.unit_cost, inv.quantity * inv.unit_cost as value, p.product_id, d.depot_id, TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(inv.update_date), inv.delete_status
```

Answer (score 1):

You are try to mimic a pivot table for this should use (fake ) aggregation function

```
SELECT inv.inventory_id
  , p.product_name
  , p.product_type
  , p.product_distributor as distributor
  , p.product_category as category
  , d.depot_name as location
  , inv.quantity
  , inv.lower_limit
  , inv.unit_cost
  , inv.quantity * inv.unit_cost as value
  , p.product_id, d.depot_id
  , TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(inv.update_date) as last_update
  , inv.delete_status
  , max(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Jan-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS janQuantityTotal
  , max(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Feb-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS febQuantityTotal
  , max(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Mar-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS marQuantityTotal
  , max(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Apr-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS aprQuantityTotal
  , max(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "May-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS mayQuantityTotal
  , max(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Jun-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS junQuantityTotal
  , max(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Jul-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS julQuantityTotal
  , max(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Aug-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS augQuantityTotal
  , max(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Sep-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS sepQuantityTotal
  , max(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Oct-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS octQuantityTotal
  , max(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Nov-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS novQuantityTotal
  , max(IF(agg_sd.mon_year = "Dec-{{ execution_date.year }}", agg_sd.totalQuantity, 0)) AS decQuantityTotal      
FROM iprocure_stage.inventory inv
JOIN iprocure_ods.product p ON p.product_id = inv.product_id 
JOIN iprocure_ods.depot d ON d.depot_id = inv.depot_id
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%b-%Y', transaction_date) mon_year, product_id, depot_id, SUM(quantity) as totalQuantity
     FROM `iprocure_ods.inventorytransaction`
     WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) = {{ execution_date.year }}
                AND transaction_type = 1 AND (reference_type = 1 OR reference_type = 6) AND delete_status = 0
                GROUP BY mon_year, product_id, depot_id 
 ) AS agg_sd ON agg_sd.product_id = inv.product_id AND agg_sd.depot_id = inv.depot_id
GROUP BY inv.inventory_id
  , p.product_name
  , p.product_type
  , p.product_distributor as distributor
  , p.product_category as category
  , d.depot_name as location
  , inv.quantity
  , inv.lower_limit
  , inv.unit_cost
  , inv.quantity * inv.unit_cost as value
  , p.product_id, d.depot_id
  , TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(inv.update_date) as last_update
  , inv.delete_status
```